# Mocha test suite halted on uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I can't prevent an **Uncaught Async Exception** from halting a suite of mocha tests. It seems like it should fail just the test, but the mocha process exits. For the given test cases:

```
describe('AsyncWow', () => {

    it('should proceeed after this test', (done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            throw new Error('boom');
            done();
        });
    });

    it('but never gets here', (done) => {
        done();
    });

});
```

**Produces terminal output:**

```
  AsyncWow

/source/test/foo.test.js:6
         throw new Error('boom');
               ^
Error: boom
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (/source/test/foo.test.js:6:16)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is halting because the `done()` never gets called( as after error, it searches for exception handler, and the next line is never touched),

I would change the code to...

```
describe('AsyncWow', () => {
    it('should proceeed after this test', (done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            try{
                throw new Error('boom');
                done(new Error('This line should not be reached.'));
            }catch(e){
                done(); 
            }

        });
    });
    it('but never gets here', (done) => {
        done();
    });
});
```

or if you want the error to fail the test...

```
describe('AsyncWow', () => {
    it('should proceeed after this test', (done) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            try{
                throw new Error('boom');
                done();
            }catch(e){
                done(e); 
            }

        });
    });
    it('but never gets here', (done) => {
        done();
    });
});
```